# Is there some way in fuzzy query builder to identify if any record is a perfect match?

Tags: elasticsearch, fuzzy-search

I have some fuzzy query written as below -

`MatchQueryBuilder fuzzyQuery = QueryBuilders.matchQuery("color","blue color").fuzziness(Fuzziness.AUTO).fuzzyTranspoistions(true);`

`BoolQueryBuilder bool = new BoolQueryBuilder();`

`bool.should(fuzzyQuery);`

`SeachSourceBuilder search = new SearchSourceBuilder();`

`search.query(bool);`

`SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(<index>,<type>)`

`searchRequest .source(search)`

`SearchResponse res = client.search(searchRequest,RequestOptions.DEFAULT);`

'res' returns some records from elastic search where the column 'color' has values similar to the string 'blue color'.

Now is there some way I can identify if any of the result records contain the field 'color' with exact value 'blue color'?

Thanks.

Comment: consider to use the hit score (higher for a perfect match)

Comment: thanks for the reply. yes I already tried with hit score. But from what I have seen we don't have an exact common hit score value for the perfect match. So the record with the highest hit score is the closest matching record, but need not necessarily the exact match.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding an exact-match query to your fuzzy query, and boost the exact-match query with a significant boosting factor to make the exact matches standing out. Something like

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "color": {
              "query": "blue color",
              "fuzziness": "auto",
              "fuzzy_transpositions": "true"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "color.keyword": {
              "value": "blue color",
              "boost": 1000
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

which leads to results like this

```
...
"hits" : [
  {
    "_index" : "so-score",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "IYG5C3AB1HeSr1rnK_bY",
    "_score" : 1205.3591,
    "_source" : {
      "color" : "blue color"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "so-score",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "IoG5C3AB1HeSr1rnPfZA",
    "_score" : 1.2476649,
    "_source" : {
      "color" : "blue bolor"
    }
  },
...
```